# GDI+ problems on windows XP

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I am using GDI+ to render login window. It all works fine on windows 7, but
on windows XP (SP3 with all updates) there's absolutely no output.

Code in WM_PAINT

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC         hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );
Graphics    *graphics= new Graphics( hdc );

if ( graphics->Clear( BACKGROUND_COLOR ) != Ok )
{
    LOGGER << "LoginWindow::Error clearing surface" << endl;
    goto clean;
}

if ( graphics->DrawImage( dialogHeader, 0, 0, dialogHeaderSize.cx, dialogHeaderSize.cy ) != Ok )
{
    LOGGER << "LoginWindow::Error drawing image" << endl;
    goto clean;
}

if ( graphics->DrawRectangle( dialogBorderPen, 0, 0, LOGIN_WINDOW_WIDTH - 1, LOGIN_WINDOW_HEIGHT - 1 ) != Ok )
{
    LOGGER << "LoginWindow::Error drawing rectangle" << endl;
    goto clean;
}

clean:
delete graphics;
EndPaint( hwnd, &ps );
```

dialogHeader is a .png image loded with following code:

```
dialogHeader = Bitmap::FromFile( imagePath );
```

GDI+ is initialized like this:

```
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
Status              gdiplusStatus;
ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;

gdiplusStatus = GdiplusStartup( &gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL );

if ( gdiplusStatus != Ok )
{
    LOGGER << "Main::Failed to initialize GDI+. ErrorCode=" << gdiplusStatus << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Some known facts:

- Painting code always executes successfully (verified with debugger - Visual Studio 2010)
- Image is loaded without error
- This occurs whether windows themes/aero is turned off or on
- When I drag window on windows XP out of screen and then back the image is displayed like this:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/851/winxp2.png/

Output on windows 7

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/824/win7p.png/

Output on windows XP

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/839/winxpu.png/

I hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: You'll probably repro the problem on Win7 by turning off Aero.  The cause it not apparent from your snippet.  Can't see where hdc came from.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether I have themes/aero turned on or off, result is always the same :(. Oh and hdc came from hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );

Comment: Is GDI+ properly initialized? (may be Win7 do that by itself at program loading ...): What is the gdiplusStatus in XP ?

Comment: GDI+ is initialized and gdiplusStatus is Ok.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you add an explicit InvalidateRgn?

Comment: I placed it after ShowWindow, but its still the same :(

Comment: I created new project (visual studio 2010 - win32) using only code above and it now works on both os. So it must be something in the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was a combination of WS_EX_COMPOSITED style and GDI+ custom painting. If i enable this flag, nothing is initially drawn on windows XP. Only after resizing, things start appearing.

After some research i found out its probably a bug. There is a **workaround** however:

1. Create a DIB section HBITMAP (or you could try a standard HBITMAP) in memory and select it into an HDC (Look at **CreateCompatibleBitmap** and **CreateCompatibleDC** and also 
   **SelectObject**).
2. Make sure to create the HBITMAP the size of the client window.
3. Now, use this "memory" HDC when calling:

   ```
   Graphics graphics (m_hDC);
   ```
4. When GDI+ is finished drawing to the memory HDC, then call BitBlt to draw the image on the pDC.

Comment: Must on WndProc to call ::BeginPaint(), not in OnPaint/OnDraw?